# how can I retrieve user's login id from mysql using global variable in my android app?

Tags: php, android, mysql

I am very new in android.In my app I want when a user login that user's id is carried all activity.Like a session management.That user id comes from mysql database.I want to carry login user id to all tab which shows in main activity.I tried global variable but its didn't work.please give me some solutions....

**LoginActivity**

```
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {

    // Get text from email and passord field
    String email = UsernameEt.getText().toString();
    String password = PasswordEt.getText().toString();
    String type = "login";
    BackgroundWorker backgroundWorker = new BackgroundWorker(this);
    backgroundWorker.execute(type, email, password);
    //finish();
    Intent intent = new Intent(UserLogin.this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();

}
```

**BackgroundWorker class**

```
public class BackgroundWorker extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {

Context context;
AlertDialog alertDialog;


BackgroundWorker (Context ctx){

    context = ctx;

}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

    String type = params[0];
    String login_url = "http://www.mybusket.com/pmsapp/webs/get_all_emp.php";
    if (type.equals("login")){

        try {
            String email_id = params[1];
            String password = params[2];
            URL url = new URL(login_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
            String post_data = URLEncoder.encode("email_id", "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(email_id, "UTF-8")+"&"
                    +URLEncoder.encode("password", "UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(password, "UTF-8");
            bufferedWriter.write(post_data);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            outputStream.close();
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream, "iso-8859-1"));
            String result="";
            String line="";
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine())!= null){
                result += line;
            }
            bufferedReader.close();
            inputStream.close();
            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            return result;
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    return null;
}
```

From this class Validate email address..How can I carry logged in user's id which save in mysql database, to all activity.

Comment: Why don't you retrieve id from database itself in your all activities?

Comment: Try using shared Preferences.

Comment: You can use SharedPreferences, or create an User class which is singeton and inside a class that extends Application or you can use SQLite database. Both approaches work well but the most easiest one is SharedPrefernces but to implement log out logic you should set user parameters to and save SharedPreferences.

Answer (score 0):

Android apps are not web apps so yo don't need to "carry" anything.

If you need to store the userId to be shared with different activities, you can put it in SharedPreferences.

[SharedPreverences doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

Comment: Use SharedPreferences